# Python3 - merge sort, O(n) space efficiency

Tags: python, beginner, sorting, mergesort

Any critique of my implementation of Merge sort would be much appreciated!  I tested it using a driver function (shown below), and everything works.  However, it still feels unwieldy, I am a beginner so I really want to hear any criticisms, constructive or not :)

```
def inplace_merge_sort( lst, start = 0 , end = None ):
  def inplace_merge( lst1_start, lst1_end , lst2_start, lst2_end ): #needs to take in two sets of unsorted indices 
    start, end = lst1_start, lst2_end
    for _ in range( (end - start) ):
      if(lst[lst1_start] < lst[lst2_start]):
        lst1_start += 1

      else:
        lst.insert(lst1_start , lst[lst2_start])
        del lst[lst2_start + 1]
        lst1_start += 1
        lst2_start += 1

      if( lst1_start == lst2_start or lst2_start == lst2_end):
        break

    return start, end #returns indices of sorted newly sublist



  if( len(lst) == 1 or len(lst) == 0): #catches edge cases
    return lst

  if end is None: end = len(lst) #so I don't have to input parameters on first call 

  
  length_sublist = end - start 

  if( length_sublist > 1):
    start1, end1 = inplace_merge_sort( lst, start, (end + start) // 2  )
    start2, end2 = inplace_merge_sort( lst, (end + start) // 2 , end  )
  
    return inplace_merge(start1, end1, start2, end2)

  else: 
    return start, end
```

Here is the test function

```
def inplace_driver_helper(f_n):
  def modified_list_returner( lst ):
    f_n(lst)
    return lst
  return modified_list_returner

def driver(f_n):
  # NICK I added these two test cases to catch some popular edge cases.
    assert f_n([]) == []
    assert f_n([4]) == [4]

    assert f_n([1,2,3]) == [1,2,3]

    assert f_n([3,2,1]) == [1,2,3]

    assert f_n([1,2,3,1,2,3]) == [1,1,2,2,3,3]

    assert f_n([1,2,3,1,1,2,3]) == [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]

    assert f_n([-1,0,46,2,3,1,2,3]) == [-1,0,1,2,2,3,3,46]
```

and when we run this,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver(inplace_driver_helper(inplace_merge_sort))

    print('done')
```

The output is 'done'!

Answer (score 16):

- Merge is usually O(m) time, where m is the number of elements involved in the merge. Due to your insertions and deletions, it's rather O(mn), where n is the length of the entire list. That makes your whole sort O(n^2 log n) time instead of mergesort's usual O(n log n).
- You call it inplace sort, which suggests it doesn't return anything, but you do return the list if it's short and you return some start/end indices otherwise. Rather inconsistent and confusing. I'd make it not return anything (other than the default `None`).
- Your function offers to sort only a part of the list, but you don't test that.
- You use quite a few rather long variable names. I'd use shorter ones, especially `i` and `j` for the main running indices.
- You insert before you delete. This might require the entire list to be reallocated and take O(n) extra space if it doesn't have an extra spot overallocated. Deleting (or popping) before inserting reduces that risk and thus increases the chance that you only take O(log n) extra space.
- Mergesort ought to be stable. Yours isn't, as in case of a tie, your merge prefers the right half's next value. For example, you turn `[0, 0.0]` into `[0.0, 0]`.

A modified version:

```
def inplace_merge_sort(lst, start=0, stop=None):
    """Sort lst[start:stop]."""

    def merge(i, j, stop):
        """Merge lst[i:j] and lst[j:stop]."""
        while i < j < stop:
            if lst[j] < lst[i]:
                lst.insert(i, lst.pop(j))
                j += 1
            i += 1

    if stop is None:
        stop = len(lst)

    middle = (start + stop) // 2
    if middle > start:
        inplace_merge_sort(lst, start, middle)
        inplace_merge_sort(lst, middle, stop)
        merge(start, middle, stop)
```

Oh, I renamed `end` to `stop`, as that's what Python mostly uses, for example:

```
>>> help(slice)
Help on class slice in module builtins:

class slice(object)
 |  slice(stop)
 |  slice(start, stop[, step])
```

```
>>> help(list.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(self, value, start=0, stop=9223372036854775807, /)
```

````
>>> help(range)
Help on class range in module builtins:

class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
```
````

Comment: Thank you, this is so much cleaner!  To confirm my understanding, your new function fixes the return issue (bullet two) because now if the length of the sub-list is <1 the function just does nothing.
 
Also a second question I had regarding bullet one, would your new function still be O(mn) because insert and pop operations are linear?  Would a way around this be to use a Linked List or something?

Comment: @JosephGutstadt Yes, as I don't have an explicit `return ...`, it only returns the default `None`. Not the list and not the start/end. Yes, the complexity is still the same, as I kept your insert/delete way (it's the only thing that makes it different from normal implementations, and thus the only thing that makes it interesting :-). And if the data is *given* as a linked list, then yes, you can merge with O(m) time and O(1) space. Of course if you're given a `list` and then convert it to some linked list, that extra linked list then costs O(n) space.

Comment: Nice that makes sense, but wait if it was a LinkedList wouldn't the List accesors inside of the merge function take extra time?  Sorry just trying to figure out how inplace merge could be O(log(n)*n) in time, since regular merge is

Comment: @JosephGutstadt What do you mean with list accessors? Like `lst[i]`? That would cost extra time, yes. Which is why you wouldn't do that :-). You'd work with references to the current list nodes, so accessing their values is O(1).

Comment: yes that was what I was talking about :).  I think that makes sense, so at a high level we would replace the start, middle, and stop indices with actual pointers to parts in the LL?

Comment: @JosephGutstadt Yes.

Comment: "Deleting (or popping) before inserting reduces that risk and thus increases the chance that you only take O(log n) extra space." While technically true, this doesn't affect big-O, and it's unlikely to matter; both `insert` and `del` are `O(n)` operations; even when no reallocation is needed, they need to move every element above the point of insertion/deletion. Sure, the real work might drop from `n` (in the rare cases the `insert` requires a realloc) to `n/2` (on average), but most of the time you wouldn't be paying the `n` anyway, and you still need to pay the `n/2` regardless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not sure why you're talking about *time* there. I'm talking about *space* there. Note that the OP even put "space efficiency" into the title. And they're clearly trying to use little extra space. So I'd say space usage really *does* matter here. And in most cases they will use only O(log n) extra space, especially when they delete/pop before inserting. My bullet point about *time* complexity is four bullet points further up and already contains what you just said.

Comment: hey superb, was just looking at this again, shouldn't we replace "lst.insert(i, lst.pop(j))" with something like lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

Comment: @JosephGutstadt And then do what?

Comment: I think that is sufficient, because swapping the two elements is constant time, whereas insert and delete is n time?

Comment: @JosephGutstadt Sure, it becomes faster, but it also becomes wrong. So how do you make up for that?

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to Code Review!

### PEP-8

Python has a style guide to help developers write clean, maintainable and readable code. It is referred to [as PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). A few points of note:

1. Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:
2. Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

### Type hinting

Yet another [PEP (PEP-484) for](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) putting in type hints for your variables and function parameters.

### Comments

Except for the comment in testing driver about corner cases, all other comments are actually not needed. The code explains what the comments are trying to say anyway.

### Loop over range

You have a loop with range:

```
for _ in range( (end - start) ):
```

where you actually make use of `lst1_start`. Why not start iterating from this index itself?

### Names

The variable names: `length_sublist`, `lst1_start/end` and similarly `lst2_start/end` are more readable (and sensible) as `sublist_length`, `start1/end1`, `start2/end2`. Since you do not have 2 different lists anywhere, `lst1/2` are more confusing.

### Testing

The driver for your test environment requires its own wrapper, which the testing suite needs to incorporate. This feels wrong, and should be handled by the test driver itself. Also, python provides an excellent [testing module, `unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html). For the driver:

```
@inplace_driver_helper
def driver(f_n):
    # rest of your code
```

is enough.

Answer (score 2):

- You define `inplace_merge()` inside the definition of `inplace_merge_sort()`, but it doesn't use any of the context of `inplace_merge_sort()`, so it isn't necessary.

  If you defined it outside of the definition (perhaps with a leading underscore in the identifier to warn clients it was not meant to be used directly), you would get three advantages:

  - The definition would only be executed once on import, and not on every call.
  - It could be tested directly.
  - The `start` and `end` identifiers wouldn't hide other identifiers of the same name, and risk confusing a reader about which they referred to.
- If you replaced:

  ```
   if( len(lst) == 1 or len(lst) == 0): #catches edge cases
  ```

  with

  ```
   if len(lst) <= 1:
  ```

then the length wouldn't need to be calculated twice (which, to be fair, is probably not a slow operation).

- I agree with other answers that there should be no return value, but if there is, you should be testing it. (In fact, I would test that it always returns None.)

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't use any of the context"? It does use `lst`. Very good points, though.

Comment: @superbrain: *squints* Oh dear. You are absolutely right. Sorry to the OP. I would still recommend moving it out, but a speed test might be worthwhile to see if the extra parameter requited makes it take longer.

Comment: I do see a significant speed difference in [a pure test](https://repl.it/repls/DemandingLoyalVisitors#main.py), but I suspect in the real code with the high merge costs, it'll be invisible. But might make a slight noticeable difference with a normal merge.

Comment: @superbrain: That timing test supports my naive recommendation to move the function out (presumably because of the reason I cited: "The definition would only be executed once on import, and not on every call.") But based on your observation that `lst` is used in the function, an additional `lst` parameter would need to be added to the function, and that may have a greater impact (because it is frequently called) that outweighs the small benefit. [A timing test confirmed at about 10-20 calls, the cost of the param outweighs the cost of the definition.]

Comment: Right, a test [with a list](https://repl.it/repls/QuickwittedExcellentRule#main.py) is more relevant. The nested function seems to suffer *more* from that, though.